# Vuejs deploy to IIS Default Web Site application

Tags: vue.js, iis, webpack

I need help deploying a VueJS application to the IIS Default Web Site as an additional application.

I can add the built Vue site as its own IIS Web Site on a new port(other than port 80). I change the vue.config.js publicPath property to './' and point the new site to the built 'dist' folder. THIS WORKS FINE

What i cannot get working is when i try to add a new 'Application' under the Default Web Site. This allows you to use the default port(80) and just append the 'Alias' name to the URL. ex - localhost/myvuesite

Ive gotten this to work fine in the past with other company ASP.NET websites but i cannot get this working with Vue. When i try to navigate to my newly created site, localhost/myvuesite, i just get a blank page with nothing to display. When i inspect the chrome source it appears that the site downloaded the .js and .css and index.html files but something is not working correctly.

**web.config in 'dist' directory:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <rewrite>
      <rules>
        <rule name="Handle History Mode and custom 404/500" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url="(.*)" />
          <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
          </conditions>
          <action type="Rewrite" url="/" />
        </rule>
      </rules>
    </rewrite>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

**vue.config.js:**

```
module.exports = {
  publicPath: './',
  productionSourceMap: false
};
```

**File structure:**

```
myvuesite
- css
- img
- js
- favicon.ico
- index.html
- web.config
```

Comment: Convert all absolute links to relative ones. The base tag works only for relative URLs.<script src=/js/chunk-vendors.ae4d0fb4.js> to <script src=./js/chunk-vendors.ae4d0fb4.js>

Comment: @JalpaPanchal So if i manually change the dist/index.html to add the './' to the script tags i do get my login page as expected. But its now showing in the url 'localhost/login' instead of 'localhost/myvuesite/login', once i do successfully login, the site now breaks because the '/myvuesite' get pulled out of the url.

Comment: could you share your folder structure and error detail of console?

Comment: Console errors are:

app.dc7075b4.js:1 GET http://localhost/js/chunk-29ed88a4.407ecf3e.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)

Uncaught (in promise) Error: Loading chunk chunk-29ed88a4 failed.
(error: http://localhost/js/chunk-29ed88a4.407ecf3e.js)
    at HTMLScriptElement.s (app.dc7075b4.js:1)

I updated the original question with file structure.

Comment: @JalpaPanchal Updated data

Comment: I could not understand what is your exact error. I suggest you take a snapshot of error and share image.